# SQL query fails after changing from WHERE to JOIN

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to change an implicit join by WHERE clause to a JOIN statement for a `table2` table. I've been facing a wierd SQL error. I couldn't make a simplified version to reproduce error, so here are full queries.

This works:

```
    SELECT SELECT
      *
FROM table1 s
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = t.OBYW_ID
LEFT JOIN table3 k ON s.kasta_id = k.id
LEFT JOIN table4 m ON m.id = k.mpk_id
LEFT JOIN table5 a ON a.symbol=SUBSTR(m.kod,-5)
LEFT JOIN table6 t ON t.prac_id=s.prac_id 
LEFT JOIN table7 wf ON t.firm_id=wf.firm_id
LEFT JOIN table8 kraj ON kraj.ID = t.KRAJ_ST_ID
LEFT JOIN table9 powiat ON powiat.ID = t.POWIAT_ST_ID
WHERE
SUBSTR(t.nr_ew, 1, 1) NOT IN (0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6)*
    FROM table6 t
    LEFT JOIN table2 ob ON ob.ID = t.OBYW_ID
```

This also works:

```
SELECT
       *
FROM table1 s,
     table3 k,
     table4 m,
     table5 a,
     table6 t,  --← ← ← ← ← ←
     table2,   --← ← ← ← ← ←
     table7 wf,
     table8 kraj,
     table9 powiat
WHERE t.prac_id=s.prac_id
    AND s.kasta_id = k.id
    AND m.id = k.mpk_id
    AND a.symbol=SUBSTR(m.kod,-5)
    AND table2.id=t.obyw_id   --← ← ← ← ← ←
    AND t.firm_id=wf.firm_id
    AND kraj.ID = t.KRAJ_ST_ID
    AND powiat.ID = t.POWIAT_ST_ID
    AND SUBSTR(t.nr_ew, 1, 1) NOT IN (0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6)
```

And this does not work:

```
SELECT
      *
FROM table1 s,
     table3 k,
     table4 m,
     table5 a,
     table6 t,
     table7 wf,
     table8 kraj,
     table9 powiat
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = t.OBYW_ID
WHERE t.prac_id=s.prac_id
    AND s.kasta_id = k.id
    AND m.id = k.mpk_id
    AND a.symbol=SUBSTR(m.kod,-5)
    AND t.firm_id=wf.firm_id
    AND kraj.ID = t.KRAJ_ST_ID
    AND powiat.ID = t.POWIAT_ST_ID
    AND SUBSTR(t.nr_ew, 1, 1) NOT IN (0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6)
```

With error: `Error executing SQL statement. ORA-00904: "T"."OBYW_ID": bad identifier.` I use the Oracle SQL.

We've changed requirements so we don't need that join, which is a hilarious workaround... But anyway it will come back at some point and I'll be stuck again.

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT**: The solution is:

```
SELECT
      *
FROM table1 s
LEFT JOIN table6 t ON t.prac_id=s.prac_id 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = t.OBYW_ID
LEFT JOIN table3 k ON s.kasta_id = k.id
LEFT JOIN table4 m ON m.id = k.mpk_id
LEFT JOIN table5 a ON a.symbol=SUBSTR(m.kod,-5)
LEFT JOIN table7 wf ON t.firm_id=wf.firm_id
LEFT JOIN table8 kraj ON kraj.ID = t.KRAJ_ST_ID
LEFT JOIN table9 powiat ON powiat.ID = t.POWIAT_ST_ID
WHERE
SUBSTR(t.nr_ew, 1, 1) NOT IN (0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Then arcane rules about scoping won't affect your queries (among a myriad of other benefits to using modern syntax).

Comment: try moving `t_prac t,` from line 7 to line 10.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal It worked, thanks. I switched to joins anyway, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mix old-style Oracle joins and SQL Standard explicit join syntax in the same statement.

In the standard syntax, using the keyword JOIN, the join condition applies to the tables that appear immediately before and immediately after the keyword JOIN. You can't join to a table declared three lines earlier.

Change ALL the `WHERE` join conditions to explicit `JOIN` conditions, making sure each `JOIN` condition goes in the right place. That is actually one of the advantages of the Standard syntax: it is much clearer what goes with what.

**EDIT**: To be precise, the way I phrased it in the second paragraph isn't exactly right. JOIN conditions can refer to earlier tables, not just the one right above that condition. But they can only refer to earlier tables *that were joined using the JOIN syntax*, they cannot refer to earlier tables *that were joined using the Oracle syntax, with table names separated by commas and join conditions in the WHERE clause.*

Answer (score 1):

> ORA-00904: "T"."OBYW_ID": bad identifier

This comes from mixing the old (implicit) JOIN syntax with the ANSI 92 syntax. Use one or the other (preferably explicit INNER JOINs).

Yes, this does mean you have to rewrite your whole query.